# Распознавание текста

Tags: python, tesseract

pytesseract не распознает текст, что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import os

import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

path = os.getcwd() + r'\tesseract\tesseract.exe'
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path
text = repr(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('ingame4.png'), "rus"))
print(repr(text))
```

Вывод: "' \n\x0c'"

Comment: Попробуйте нормализовать входные данные. То есть на вход подать изображение исключительно с текстом. Думаю OCR попросту не может определить начальную позицию текста из-за избытка шума на изображении.

Comment: То есть обрезать скриншот?

Comment: «То есть на вход подать изображение исключительно с текстом». Ну может вы и с cv2 мастерить горазды. Да, обрезать..

Comment: Я у вас код посмотрел, просто мне важно также учитывать разрешение игры.